# Devise change the user_omniauth_callback route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working with OmniAuth to use Facebook Connect in my Devise based rails app. One of the routes it creates is:

`user_omniauth_callback      /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) {:action=>/facebook/, :controller=>"devise/omniauth_callbacks"}`

I'd like to modify this route to a custom URL. Where would be the right place to do that?

the problem is by default, the route it creates is http://foo/users/auth/:action/callback.format. I want to have something more custom like http://foo/prefix_path/users/auth/:action/callback.format. I tried making my routes file look like the following:

```
  scope "/mypath" do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  end
```

but it still generates the wrong route:

`user_omniauth_callback      /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) {:action=>/facebook/, :controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, I assume you want to have your own custom code for the callback.

You can extend the devise controller such as:

```
class MyOmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
     #Custom Code here
  end

end
```

Then you can register this new controller in your routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "my_omniauth_callbacks"}
```

EDIT:

devise can also take a 'path' option in the devise_for so changing the route:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "my_omniauth_callbacks"}, :path => "path_prefix/users"
```

Comment: I updated my question above to better explain what I mean with a custom route.

Comment: Updated answer to better reflect your question.

Comment: @Olives, I'm in a similar position.  We have a rails app deployed to a subdirectory on a server, e.g. `https://www.example.com/subdir/` and on different servers it might be in different subdirs, so we can't hard code the path.  Your answer about the :path option is tantalising, but has the path hard coded.  Thanks for your answer, though, I'll give both options a try.

Comment: @Olives, I gave the :path option a try, but it does not work for me.  It redirects to what looks like the correct URL, but I get a 404 error.  Will give the other option a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsatisfied with omniauthable in devise itself, then you may consider implementing omniauth as separate gem and then just tie it with device.
To modify routes, you may use :match as well and map those routes to omniauth_callbacks url. Didn't get why you want to

> I'd like to modify this route to a custom URL.

Decribe what you want to make different that what is available.